# Strange behavior when using \f@size in an argument

Tags: latex-misc, tex-general

I spotted this behaviour when pasting InkScape-generated LaTeX source directly into a LaTeX document. This source includes among other definitions the TeX command `\f@size`, surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, and I would like to pass it as an argument to a `\subfloat` command.

In the following MWE, commenting in/out the corresponding lines exhibit this behavior:

```
\begin{filecontents}{ext.tex}
  \makeatletter\f@size\makeatother
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \subfloat{
      % \input{ext} % <-- OK (but extra file is undesired)
      \makeatletter\f@size\makeatother % <-- creates LaTeX ERROR
    }
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(You should see the same behaviour without using the `filecontents` package.)
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: your \makeatletter is too late, it is inside the argument, at that time the catcode of @ is in \f@size is already frozen. You can use  `\csname f@size\endcsname` then you don't need the \makeatletter.

Comment: this is unrelated to `\subfloat` it applies to any argument of any latex macro.

Comment: @Ulrike: Moving the `\makeatletter` outside the argument of `\subfloat` works. Thanks. I'm including InkScape files as is, but I realise that two `\makeatletter`s (mine and the one from InkScape) don't seem to do any harm here.

Comment: @David: Thanks for clarifying that. I will change the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in comments.